# Library integration to setup file for my application

Tags: python, optimization

I have an optimisation problem to solve in Python. I can do it successfully by using **Pulp** library and **GLPK** solver. It works like a charm in my computer. But after i make a setup for that application in **Pyinstaller** and **InnoSetup**, i get an error "GLPK is not defined" in the command prompt when trying to execute it in other computers. So I tried to import library files located in GLPK's **Bin** folder to application folder together with Pulp files. Also copied them to PULP's **Solvers** folder. It didnt work again. Can you help me fix this issue, please?

Thanks in advance.